# Ensuring only one instance per scope in Dagger2

Tags: android, dagger-2, scoping

So, what I am trying to accomplish is to ensure that I have only one instance per scope in Dagger2.

Default Singleton scope already works that way. No matter on how many places you inject same object, let's call it `GlobalInstance`, method `GlobalInstance provideGlobalInstance()` that constructs it will be called once and only once.

On the other side, if I define custom scope, for example `@SessionScope` and inside some `SessionModule` I make method `User provideUser()`, that method (and, consequentially, `new User()` constructor) will be called as many times as I am injecting `User`. No matter if I use the same module instance every time, `User provideUser()` is being called for every `@Inject User mUser` I have in my code, resulting with multiple instances, instead of one scope-limited "singleton".

Is there some clear way to achieve it, using regular Dagger api. One way to do it is to have lazy getters inside the module class, but it is not very clean way to do it.

Comment: You should use the same Component to ensure that you inject the instance that belongs to the given Component

Comment: Ok, so, instead of persisting a module, I should persist somehow whole component, right? What are the best practice for doing it? Some static/global components cache?

Comment: Yeah, typically yes. I've seen `static` for Application-level @Singleton scope, and `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()` for Activity. `Map<Something, Object>` otherwise where they store the component to some key in the map

Comment: Thanks, you've helped me :)

Comment: `Map<Something, Object>` great, now we're looking for components almost the same way Service Locator does. Though, I can't think of any better approach. Now that the question is 4 years old, have you seen any "better" implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that `@Singleton` scope is functionally equivalent to any other custom scope you define.

It means that you could have two flavors of `@Provides` methods in `SessionModule`:

- `@Provides @SessionsScope` - provides "session singletons" (more on this later)
- `@Provides` - provides new object on each injection

Please note that the term "singleton" have some ambiguity when we talk about Dagger, therefore I prefere to use term "scoped objects". When scoped object injected with Dagger for the first time, the component caches its instance and returns it on each subsequent injections PERFORMED BY THE SAME COMPONENT.

For more information you can read this post: [Android Dagger 2 Scopes Demistified](http://www.techyourchance.com/dagger-2-scopes-demystified/)

Comment: I assumed that custom scopes are not different than provided Singleton, but, as I described, I've got different behavior. It seems that is the issue is what EpicPandaForce has explained in comment - I should not use just same module but rather whole component, if I don't want provide*() methods to be called more than once per scope.

Comment: @SadClown, please read the blog post I referenced - it explains these relationships in details. There is also a tutorial app on github that shows one possible approach to handling components.

Comment: Sorry if I look rude, but I went trough the post and haven't found my answer. But I solved my problem, combining your and EpicPandaForce's answer. Thanks.

Comment: @SadClown, I didn't imply that you are rude, but there is only so much information one can post in an answer. Glad you found a solution.

Comment: Argh, my bad, there IS the hint towards the answer in the post you've shared. I found it in one sentence that I've overseen somehow.